# context is unavailable in python behave

Tags: python-behave

I am starting with Python behave and got stuck when trying to access context - it's not available. Here is my code:

Here is the Feature file:

```
Feature: Company staff inventory
    Scenario: count company staff
            Given a set of employees:
                    | name | dept |
                    | Paul | IT   |
                    | Mary | IT   |
                    | Pete | Dev  |

    When we count the number of employees in each department
    Then we will find two people in IT
    And we will find one employee in Dev
```

Here is the Steps file:

```
from behave import *
@given('a set of employees')
def step_impl(context):
        assert context is True
@when('we count the number of employees in each department')
def step_impl(context):
        context.res = dict()
        for row in context.table:
                for k, v in row:
                        if k not in context.res:
                                context.res[k] = 1
                        else:
                                context.res[k] += 1
@then('we will find two people in IT')
def step_impl(context):
        assert context.res['IT'] == 2
@then('we will find one employee in Dev')
def step_impl(context):
        assert context.res['Dev'] == 1
```

Here's the Traceback:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/kseniyab/Documents/broadsign_code/spikes/BDD_Gherkin/behave/src/py3behave/lib/python3.4/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1456, in run
          match.run(runner.context)
        File "/home/kseniyab/Documents/broadsign_code/spikes/BDD_Gherkin/behave/src/py3behave/lib/python3.4/site-packages/behave/model.py", line 1903, in run
          self.func(context, *args, **kwargs)
        File "steps/count_staff.py", line 5, in step_impl
          assert context is True
      AssertionError
```

Answer (score 0):

The `context` object *is* there. It is your assertion that is problematic:

```
assert context is True
```

fails because `context` *is* not `True`. The only thing that can satisfy `x is True` is where `x` has been set to `True`. `context` has not been set to `True`. It is an object. Note that testing whether `context is True` is not the same as testing whether if you were to write `if context:` the true branch would be taken or the false branch. The latter is equivalent to testing whether `bool(context) is True`.

There's no point in testing whether `context` is available. It is always there.

Comment: hmm, but when I try to access context.table to iterate through the table I passed at given step, it returns NoneType is not iterable. So I am not able to access context.table. That was my initial problem. Do you know what might be the problem with context.table?

Comment: Oh i figured that out, `context.table` was available at given step, but cleared at when step, so I cached it as `context.data = context.table` and was able to access in subsequent steps.